# Renaming the “OK Google” voice command

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-now, voice-recognition, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have several Android devices: I would like to have a different voice command for each device to turn on the voice search. Is there any way to rename the voice command “OK Google”?

I use Android 4.4.2 on each device.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The Application Open Mic+ is the only way to do this that I've found so far. It's available for free on the Play Store. The "hotword" is one of its settings.

[Open Mic+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.RSen.OpenMic.Pheonix&hl=en)